# How to get the installation directory in C# after deploying dll's

Tags: c#, deployment, interop

Is there some smart way to retreive the installation path when working within a dll (C#) which will be called from an application in a different folder?

I'm developing an add-in for an application. My add-in is written in C#. The application that will use is written in C and needs to compile some stuff during evaluation, so I have a middlestep with a C++ dll that handles the interop business with C# and only shows a clean interface outward that C can work with.

What I deploy will be a set of .dll's and a .lib and .h for the C++ part (sometimes static binding will be necessary).

When trying out the setup and printing out the current directory info from the C# dll with:

```
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

or:

```
        Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

I get the executables path.

So ... once again, how do I get the installation path of my dll?

Edit: They both worked! Thanks for the quick reply guys!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think what you want is `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.

Answer (score 4):

One of these two ways:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Or:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).CodeBase);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
typeof(TypeInMyModule).Assembly.Location
```