# get the installation directory in c#

Tags: c#, installanywhere

I have xml file that after my application installation will located in the installation dir.
i need the application to reed this file.
how do i get the installation dir where the user install it in order to read this file.
or is a better way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the installation directory in C# after deploying dll's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333767/how-to-get-the-installation-directory-in-c-sharp-after-deploying-dlls)

Comment: Is an application executable located in the same folder as XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the assembly in which this code lies is installed to the same directory:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```