# Changing extension of file using Path.ChangeExtension

Tags: c#

1. My first method should rename filename, but it still uploads to web with same format. By logic it should work but I guess there is some problem with

   ```cs
   Path.ChangeExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName.ToLower(), ".jpg");
   ```

   because when I am debuging project it recognize file with .png format I mean with that line

   ```cs
   if (Path.GetExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower() == ".png")
   ```

   but it does not change that extension of file.

   ```cs
   if (Path.GetExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower() == ".png")
   {
       Path.ChangeExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName.ToLower(), ".jpg");
   }
   ```
2. I tried different method and it gave me that:

   > File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\1.png' is not found.

   So I am stuck here.

   ```cs
   if (Path.GetExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower() == ".png")
   {
       File.Move(create.PostedFile.FileName,
           Path.ChangeExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName, ".jpg"));
   }
   ```

Comment: "My first method should rename filename" - no, it shouldn't. `Path.ChangeExtension` doesn't change any existing data - it returns a new filename. (Just like `string.Replace` doesn't replace anything in the existing string - it returns a new string.) For the second method, it's not clear why you expected the file to exist as a local file relative to the process's working directory. It doesn't help that we don't have any context for what your application is doing.

Comment: Changing a file's extension doesn't change the format. A .png file cannot become a .jpg just by changing the extension. [You have to encode the file](https://dev.to/zawhtut/converting-png-to-jpg-image-files-in-c-4f3j).

Comment: +1 for the above comments + the method [Path.ChangeExtension()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension?view=net-6.0) expects something like **`.ext`**, not **`*.ext`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To rename a file. you should use the method `File.Rename` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.renamefile?view=net-6.0

The method `Path.ChangeExtension` to create a new file name only!

2. Becareful the destination directory, I guess the directory you deployed your app is not `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\`

Check this one.

[How to get the installation directory in C# after deploying dll's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333767/how-to-get-the-installation-directory-in-c-sharp-after-deploying-dlls)

Notice that

```cs
File.Move(create.PostedFile.FileName, Path.ChangeExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName, ".jpg"));
```

You didn't create the file before moving. You have to manually create the posted file first

Comment: Something like that File.Rename(create.PostedFile.FileName.ToLower(), ".jpg"); but it gaves me error

Comment: You have to check the file is created `create.PostedFile.FileName` and why you have to convert `toLower()` here?

Comment: And the second param is a file name (not an file extension)

Comment: I checked and create.PostedFile.FileName contain let say string 1.png, but do you use File.Rename

Comment: That file was not saved on your disk. Check it first